# Пунктуация в предложении с уточнением

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Скажите, пожалуйста, где здесь нужно ставить знаки препинания и какие?

> **А стильная стрижка() ассиметричное каре() придает образу еще больше стиля
>   и красоты**.

Правильно ли будет выделить уточнение запятыми?

Comment: Есть нехорошее слово  а к т у а л ь н о е , но оно всё же исключит повтор: «стильная даёт больше стиля».

Answer (score 1):

Смешная ошибка: дважды "а**сс**иметричное каре".

*Симметрия* пишется с двумя ***м*,** а ***а*** всего лишь приставка-отрицание, нет префикса ***ас***.

Ну и понятно, что двух "стилей" в коротком предложении быть никак не может — убрать "стильная" в начале предложения.

Как только Вы уберёте эту "стильную", вопрос о запятых рассосётся сам собой:

*А  стрижка асимметричное каре придает образу ещё больше стиля и красоты.*

Если "стильную" оставить, то равно возможно написание с запятыми и без:

*А стильная стрижка, асимметричное каре, придает образу ещё больше шарма и изящества* (тут я просто не уверена, сочетабельны ли шарм с красотой... хотя да, бывает красота без шарма).

Запятые "оправдывают" стильность (обособление уточнения); их отсутствие даёт название стильной стрижке.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта: **А стильная стрижка, асимметричное каре, придает образу еще больше выразительности  и красоты.**

Название стрижки лучше обособить, если имеется в виду, что стильная стрижка вообще важна для создания образа, а при уточнении просто указан конкретный вариант такой стрижки.